# How can I change the selection text background using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me how to change the selection text background using CSS?

Most new websites show a custom background color rather than the default blue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a tutorial for that : 
http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

```
::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
    }
::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/* Mozilla based browsers */
::-moz-selection {
   background-color: #FFA;
   color: #000;
}

/* Works in Safari */
::selection {
   background-color: #FFA;
   color: #000;
}
```

Unfortunately, it can't be done in IE.